# Is there any way I can add an image next to each item on a list without using a custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview

I need to put small icons on the right of each list item. I know it can be done with a custom list but it will mean rewiring a lot of code.  if there a way to do it without using a custom adapter?

```
mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sidebar_list);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mStrings));
        mList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Do you mean somesort of a thumbnail or an identical icon on each of the views?

Comment: @KirillKulakov a thumbnail. different for each item

Answer (score 2):

No, overriding `getView` inside a custom adapter is the only way to dynamically set different images to your list rows. However, if you want to set a static (same) image for all the row items, then you may define your custom resource xml for the row (with a `TextView` and `ImageView` or comppund drawable-TextView inside) and pass it to your default adapter when initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) and a custom layout with an ImageView.

---

Trivial example:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("text", "one");
map.put("image", String.valueOf(getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", getPackageName())));
list.add(map);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {"text", "image"}, new int[] {R.id.text, R.id.image}));
```

Comment: The OP would still need to either extend `SimpleAdapter` or create a `ViewBinder`. If the OP is truly concerned about level of effort, keeping the data in its current structure and simply extending `ArrayAdapter` is probably easier.

Comment: I'll agree that it is much faster computationally to use custom code, but I included a working example that shows this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create XML layout for the view (if you don't have one) and add an imageview.
you should give it and ID ('thubnail').Next you just ask the adapter for a certain view by its position

```
View singleView = listView.getChildAt(wantedChild);
ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) singleView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```